# IMAP login not recognizing SASL while simple postfix send is

Tags: postfix, imap, dovecot, sasl

I've got SASLAuthd working (via LDAP), and am also successfully able to telnet via port 25 with my LDAP credentials. Postfix is configured with Dovecot. All 3 services are running fine (Postfix, Dovecot, SASLAuthd)

I can also connect on port 143 however when I try to use "a login " it only applies PAM auth (ie. LDAP and presumably SASL isn't being recognized for IMAP)

> postconf -a

outputs:

> cyrus 
>   dovecot

In the **/var/log/mail.log** I see

> Apr  9 01:36:22 localhost dovecot: auth-worker(18053):
>   pam(user_x,127.0.0.1): pam_authenticate() failed: Authentication
>   failure (password mismatch?)

.. Nothing in /var/log/mail.err

Why am I not able to login via IMAP using my LDAP credentails while to send a mail via port 25 I can ?

Comment: Solution **workaround** posted @ [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/607007/dovecot-imap-port-143-not-working-with-sasl-while-postfix-port-25-is/608282#608282